# 给我站住: Idiom or common meaning

Tags: idioms, phrase

> 给我站住

I assume this means something like "wait for me!". But I still have a couple of questions.

1. Google translate gives the meaning "Nothing to say" which implies that 给我站住 may be an idiom.
2. If 给我站住 does mean "wait for me", is this the normal way of saying it? How does it differ from something like “等我”

Comment: it means `STOP!', commonly used when you are chasing someone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"给我" is usually interpreted as a command or an order to do something for the speaker.

"站住" means to halt or to stand still.

"给我站住" is not an idiom, but a command to stop a person from walking away. In this case, Google Translate got it wrong. "给我站住" is usually spoken when someone has done something bad and you want that person to stop walking away from the "crime" scene:

> 你给我站住！

"等我" is to ask someone to wait for you. Therefore, the two do not share the same meaning at all.

Comment: That's why all those police were yelling it at me :)

Comment: You did something wrong???

Comment: Only joking!­­­

Comment: Usually if you hear that from police, there could be a few guns pointing in your direction :)